# Post request from RESTful API giving UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: Product validation failed: error

Tags: javascript, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

I am working with this RESTful api and I want to send a post request to the server to create a document in the database. For that I am using model.create method. But it keeps me sending the error in the console
`UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: Product validation failed: seller: Please enter product seller, category: Please enter the product category, description: Please enter product description, name: Please enter product name` I am testing this inside postman.
Is there any bugs in my code? How can I fix this.
Here is my app.js file

```js
const express = require('express')
const mongoose = require('mongoose') 
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/playDB', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})

const playSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter product name'],
    },
    price : {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'Please enter product price'],
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter product description']
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter the product category'],
    },
    seller: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter product seller']
    },
    stock: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'Please enter product stock'],
    }
})

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', playSchema)

//get all products

app.route("/products")
        .post(async function(req, res, next){
          const product = await Product.create(req.body);

          res.send({
              success: true,
              product
          })
            
        })


app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log('server is running')
})
```

Comment: add this top of app.route `app.use(bodyParser.json());`

Comment: @mohammadNaimi I tried and it dosent work :((

Comment: could you log your req.body ?

Comment: @mohammadNaimi yes. I found the answer. I didnt coded the app.use(express.json()). Now the code works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't made express read express format. So that's why it didn't work

All I had to add was `app.use(express.json())` Then it worked